# redirect /cgi-bin/ via .htaccess 403 forbidden

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, cgi-bin

I am trying to set up a 301 redirection from "/cgi-bin/" to https://example.com/test/ with the following rule in .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /cgi-bin/ https://example.com/test/
```

but I get a 403 Forbidden error. Commenting `Options -Indexes` does not work either. If I remove the slash after "/cgi-bin/", the the redirection works.

The directory "cgi-bin" does not actually exist on the server, however since the URL https://example.com/cgi-bin/ was mentioned in our old documentations, we explicitly need a redirection  with the tailing slash after "/cgi-bin".

Comment: The Redirect directive does prefix matching, so `Redirect /foo https:/…` should still work for `/foo/` or even `/foo/bar`. Not sure why it wouldn’t here, maybe there is something special about the `cgi-bin` directory somehow. If you have mod_rewrite available, try using that instead. `RewriteEngine on`, and then `RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/ https://example.com/test/ [R=301]`

Comment: No changes. I still get the forbidden message.

Comment: Makes no sense why you should get _forbidden_ in the first place. You said the directory does not actually exist, so requesting either `/cgi-bin` or `/cgi-bin/` should get you a 404, if the rewriting wasn’t working at all. And if it does work - well then the problem would have to be at the other end, and the forbidden would have to come from requesting `/test/` then. Maybe something further up the server configuration handles this request already (`cgi-bin` is a commonly used folder name, so there might be some “default handling” for it already.)